# When zero is not None or not False but digit 0

Tags: python

In the example below `result` will be assigned to `var2` since `var1` is None:

```
var1=None
var2='June'
result=var1 or var2
```

But if `var1` is zero `result` is still assigned to `var2` because zero is considered to be the same as `None` or `False`:

```
var1=0
var2='June'
result=var1 or var2
```

How (without using `if var1!=None`) to edit this code to make sure `var1` is considered to be "valid"(not None, not False) even if its value is zero `0`?

Comment: `0` is always falsy, although `'0'` is truthy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While `or` looks pretty, it looks like you might want to go with this:

```
result = var1 if var1 is not None else var2
```

Remember in Python there are a lot of things that are falsy: 0, False, None, '', empty sequences, empty mappings, and instances of classes with `__nonzero__` and `__len__` set a certain way.

The code above allows all those things *except* `None` to give you `var1`.  Adjust accordingly.

**ADDENDUM**

For example, in Ruby, only `nil` and `false` are falsy.  Let's say you want to duplicate this behavior in Python.  You could write:

```
result = var1 if var1 is not None and var1 is not False else var2
```

However, here is a warning.  Do NOT write:

```
result = var1 if var1 not in [None,False] else var2  # FAIL! DOES NOT WORK!!!!!!
```

Why?  Because, in Python 2 at least:

```
>>> 0 is None
False
>>> 0 is False
False
>>> 0 in [None,False]
True
>>> 0 in [False]
True
>>> 0 == None
False
>>> 0 == False
True
```

Good to know, especially if one is moving to Python from Ruby.

Comment: Which falsy things _exactly_ would you like to preserve `var1`?  We may be able to get an `or` working without the repetition of `var1`, which I agree, looks ugly. :)  Are you looking for Ruby behavior, where only False and None are falsy?

Comment: I only need to keep/consider `0` zero digit as a valid entity for my application. None, False, empty strings, empty lists and etc should be all skipped and var2 used instead. But I think you nailed it down with absolute minimum code involved. Thanks!

Comment: There's always the old bool=int index trick, `(var1, var2)[var1 is None]`, but the `if/else` is much better.

Comment: Agreed, especially as this "trick" _evaluates var2_ (I think)!  In both cases `var1` is repeated, but I don't think there's a way in Python to avoid this.  Maybe someone will come around with such an answer (obfuscated or not).